# Extract embedded package files from word document using open xml?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying extract the word document, It has embedded files(word,excel,package). I am not able to extract package and save it Using C# Open XML.

The below code just extracts word and excel but not package.

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
                    {
foreach (EmbeddedPackagePart pkgPart in document.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<EmbeddedPackagePart>())
                        {
                           if (pkgpart.uri.tostring().startswith(embeddingpartstring))
                           {
                               string filename1 = pkgpart.uri.tostring().remove(0, embeddingpartstring.length);
                               // get the stream from the part
                               system.io.stream partstream = pkgpart.getstream();
                               string filepath = "d:\\test\\" + filename1;

                               // write the steam to the file.
                               system.io.filestream writestream = new system.io.filestream(filepath, filemode.create, fileaccess.write);
                               readwritestream(pkgpart.getstream(), writestream);
                           }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening, and what you expect when you say you cannot "extract package"?

Comment: GetPartsOfType<EmbeddedPackagePart>() method doesn't have the package but It has the other files like excel and word. I expect the method to extract the package and save.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is, that when you go to MainDocument.Parts and start searching, what you'll get is things like "Imagepart", "ChartPart" etc. where the ChartPart might have it's own embedded part, which could be the Excel or Word file you are looking for.

In short, you need to extend your search for embedded parts, to the actual parts in the mainDocument.

If I just wanted to extract all embedded parts in one of the files from my own project, I would go about it like this.

```
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Test\myTestDocument.docx", false))
{
    //just grab all the parts, might be relevant to be a bit more clever about it, depending on sizes of files and how many files you want to search through
    foreach(var part in document.MainDocumentPart.Parts)
    {
        //foreach part see if that part containts an EmbeddedPackagePart
        var testForEmbedding = part.OpenXmlPart.GetPartsOfType<EmbeddedPackagePart>();
        foreach(EmbeddedPackagePart embedding in testForEmbedding)
        {
            //You should probably insert some clever naming scheme here..
            string fileName = embedding.Uri.OriginalString.Split('/').Last();
            //stream the EmbeddedPackagePart to a file
            using(FileStream myFile = File.Create(@"C:\test\" + fileName))
            using (var stream = embedding.GetStream())
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                stream.CopyTo(myFile);
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Kaspar,Thanks for your reply.What I am trying to achieve is I want to extract a package object from the document. like as we extract any file(excel or powerpoint)

Comment: Code which you have mentioned will try to extract ChartPart embedded files likes which has excel sheet..

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then. Judging from the code you posted, it looks like you are trying to find embedded office-files in a word file and save them?

Comment: The code I posted extracts office embedded files. what I want is to extract package object as well.